# Python if statement not working as expected. Code 'apparently' called twice

Tags: python, if-statement, blender

I have this piece of code:

```
import bge
import GameLogic
import os

os.system("cls")
scene = GameLogic.getCurrentScene()
objects = scene.objects
objectCube = objects["Cube"]
visible = objectCube.visible
if visible == True:
    objectCube.setVisible(False, True)
else:
    objectCube.setVisible(True, True)
```

This code is supposed to toggle the visibility of an object but instead the object disappears and immediately reappears in a split second. It looks as if it just flickers. What am I doing wrong?

Also, don't worry about the other variables, they work fine. I have tested them using some Console outputs.

Comment: May not address the issue, but why not simplify the five lines to `objectCube.setVisible(not objectCube.visible, True)`?

Comment: Why not simply use `if visible:`? That's what kind-of a boolean value is for.

Comment: or `if objectCude.visible:` or @jonrsharpes idea :P

Comment: I tried all of your suggestions. They simplify the code. But still, they do not fix the issue.

Comment: Should I post this to the Blender SE community as well?

Comment: objects is a dictionary? Can you print that and add it to your question

Comment: objects is a CList of type KX_Object .. something like that doc [here](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html#bge.types.KX_GameObject)

Comment: Are you calling the code twice? That would presumably set the object invisible then visible again. If it's constantly flickering, the code may be looping and need a global variable to define whether the object should be visible or not.

Comment: Not constantly. The script is set to a Mouse Left Button Sensor. When I left-click, the object flickers once.

Comment: I don't know the utility library, but would the mouse left button sensor perhaps fire on mouse down event and again on mouse up event? Or once for mouse down event, once for mouse click event? That could easily explain it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I too thought that was the case. But it's the same issue with Wheeldown.

Comment: Other possibility might be an event being delivered to multiple layers in the display, and then propagating from another level to the one that catches it a second time. Any way to limit the mouse event handler to avoid bubbling (to use the JS term)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem:** The mouse sensor sends two signals per click, one for mouse down and one for mouse up. Mouse down sends a positive signal while mouse up sends negative.

You can test this by holding the mouse button down, the cube will disappear and when you release the mouse it will return.

**The solution:** Use the sensor's `positive` property to determine if this is a mouse up or down event.

```
import bge
import GameLogic
import os


os.system("cls")
scene = GameLogic.getCurrentScene()
objects = scene.objects
objectCube = objects["Cube"]
visible = objectCube.visible

# get the mouse sensor
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
sens = cont.sensors['Mouse']
if sens.positive: # positive means a down button event
    if visible == True:
        objectCube.setVisible(False, True)
    else:
        objectCube.setVisible(True, True)
```

Comment: This does **nothing**. Now it even stops flickering.

Comment: The name of your mouse sensor needs to match with `sens = cont.sensors['Mouse']` [This copy](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38989) works for me.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of `setVisible` set the game children objects visibility. You set it to `True`. In this case You hidden the main object and show the children objects.

Following to http://bgepython.tutorialsforblender3d.com/GameObject/setVisible `recursive` parameter does not mean `recursive show/hide all children elements` but `set the visibility to children elements to True/False`

Following to http://www.tutorialsforblender3d.com/BGE_Python/Sensors/Mouse/MouseSensor_LButton_getButtonStatus.html `mouse event` send two events `mouse press` and `mouse release`. Maybe You do not differentiate between `press` and `release` and call code twice?

Comment: Still not working. I tried `objectCube.setVisible(not(visible), False)`

Comment: I tried `objectCube.setVisible(not(visible), not(visible)` as well but in vain.

Comment: Same issue with Wheeldown.

Comment: OK Sorry all but it was a problem with my mouse itself. The problem was indeed the successive Mouse Up and Down events.